# Существует ли российский аналог RaspberryPi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Российский аналог RaspberryPi с точки зрения портативного формата с запуском линукса (с процессором, памятью, итп, сделанными в РФ) - соответствие инструкций\ядра\набора возможностей желательно но не существенно, цена в 10 раз больше тоже не проблема. Существует ли нечто подобное на российском рынке ?

Comment: Может кто либо производит на RISC-V?

Comment: Вот например https://habr.com/en/company/promwad/blog/217893/

Comment: А где это можно купить? та ссылка на которую они дают в конце на модель с Texas Instruments AM1808  и как и почти всюду например у [этих Baikal-T 900 Mhz](https://www.fastwel.ru/products/vstraivaemye-sistemy/492498/617028/odnoplatnyy-kompyuter-na-baze-dvukhyadernogo-protsessora-baikal-t1-s-shinoy-stackpc_617030_508/) и [этих RISC-V, сколково](https://syntacore.com/page/products/processor-ip/scr5) нет ни ценника ни ссылки на ритейлера - я всего то просто хочу кнопку "купить" и получить себе это к порогу...

Comment: Я не знаю. Тоже неплохо бы в проектах для госзаказа использовать такие отечественные аналоги ) Но за все время работы с нашим государством знаю только, что не ту страну назвали Гондурасом. Купите китайский.

Comment: Можете глянуть [здесь](https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=241751.0).
Характеристики похуже чем у оригинальной Малинки, да и с процент своих комплектующих не ясный, но запустить Линукс можно без особых проблем, а цена не особо то и кусается.